# "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response" with flask-assistant

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

I am testing my raspberryPi environment with using flask-assistant, ngrok and Dialogflow. When I run Simulator after simply following Quick Start tutorial in https://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html, I got an error

> "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty
>   speech response"

Do you have any idea what causes the error? Here is the error log.

> [2018-08-19 17:56:50,006] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_assistant/core.py", line 285, in _flask_assitant_view_func
>       self.intent = self.request['result']['metadata']['intentName']
>   KeyError: 'result'
>   127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2018 17:56:50] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the Flask-Assistant is supporting V2 version of Dialogflow. As per my knowledge, it only supports V1 at the moment. Try to create your Dialogflow agent using V1 and then test the Quick Start tutorial with Flask-Assistant

Comment: Thank you very much! As you kindly mentioned, V1 works fine.

Comment: Yes it did, and FYI I also changed templates/entities.yaml to fix an additional issue. Thanks!

>gender:
> - male: ['male', 'man', 'boy', 'guy', 'dude']
> - female: ['female', 'woman', 'girl', 'gal']

Comment: You may accept the answer so that others can see what they need to do in case of similar issue.